# Live streaming from remote machine webcam to wowza media server using encoder

Tags: java, rtmp, http-live-streaming, wowza, encoder

> Hi,
>
> I am working on live streaming (java) application. Where I need to
>   stream the video on wowza media server captured from webcam and from
>   there it is broadcast to multiple pc's and on devices.
>
> I tried all the encoders given on wowza official site but all are
>   softwares which i don't intended to use in my application. I need rtmp
>   encoder which is suitable to use with my application by using it i can
>   stream videos on wowza media server.
>
> So anybody successfully integrated live streaming using wowza media
>   server in java application or any reference or link which may be
>   helpful to me.
>
> Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a large working application, using a FFmpeg enconder to send authenticated RTMP, a Wowza Server with a custom Module implemetation and transcoding.

My encoding application is written in python, but for java there's the jjmpeg option, at https://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/.

FFmpeg will take care of encoding your webcam stream and send it using RTMP to your Wowza instance.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer can help me further. I got jjmpeg source from official website but it is incomplete and i can't understand how to configure it. So is there any documentation or tutorial available you know that i can integrate for my purpose.